# Spring data neo4j: Invalid syntax '$' in Cypher。 How to replace '$' with '{}'?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

The Cypher generated by spring data neo4j uses "$" to pass value, which will cause a error of Invalid Syntax by neo4j.

For example:

The Cypher generated by spring data neo4j for:

`Optional<linkType> findById(Long id);`

is

`` "MATCH ()-[r0:`linkType`]->() WHERE ID(r0)=$id WITH r0,STARTNODE(r0) AS n, ENDNODE(r0) AS m RETURN r0,n,m, ID(r0)" ``

This gets a error of Invalid Syntax.
I fixed this by use @Query:

`` @Query("MATCH ()-[r0:`linkType`]->() WHERE ID(r0)={id} WITH r0,STARTNODE(r0) AS n, ENDNODE(r0) AS m RETURN r0,n,m, ID(r0)")
Optional<linkType> findById(Long id); ``

However, when I want to use the PagingAndSortingRepository, I cannot use the @Query to fix this problem. Because it will add `SKIP $sdnSkip LIMIT $sdnLimit` at the edn automaticaly.

How can I fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Are rusing a really old version of neo4j? In neo4j 3.0, the `{foo}` syntax was [deprecated](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.0/deprecations-additions-removals-compatibility/#cypher-deprecations-additions-removals-3.0) in favor of the `$foo` syntax. In neo4j 4.0, the `{foo}` syntax was totally [removed](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.0/deprecations-additions-removals-compatibility/#cypher-deprecations-additions-removals-4.0).

Comment: @cybersam I am using old old version of neo4j :2.2.3.

Comment: You should use {variable} syntax, but ensure that you import Query annotation (org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.Query) from neo4j package, but not default spring-data Query

Answer (score 1):

You are using a really old version of neo4j (older than 3.0).

In neo4j 3.0, the `{foo}` syntax was [deprecated](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.0/deprecations-additions-removals-compatibility/#cypher-deprecations-additions-removals-3.0) in favor of the `$foo` syntax. In neo4j 4.0, the `{foo}` syntax was totally [removed](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.0/deprecations-additions-removals-compatibility/#cypher-deprecations-additions-removals-4.0).

Instead of trying to support the obsolete `{foo}` syntax, you should upgrade your neo4j installation to a more recent (ideally, the latest) version of neo4j. If you have data to upgrade, you will have to upgrade in 2 steps:

- [From your current version to 3.5](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.5/upgrade/).
- [From 3.5 to 4.x](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/upgrade/).